# Can every $KN \times KN$ matrix written as kronecker product of a $K \times K$ and and $N \times N$ matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In my current work, I have two constants $K$ and $N$ and I have to compute several kronecker products of $K \times K$ and $N \times N$ hermitian matrices to construct $KN \times KN$ matrices. This aroused my curiosity in the reverse direction. Thus for any given $KN \times KN$ complex matrix, does there exist a decomposition as a kronecker product of $K \times K$ and $N \times N$ matrix.

Comment: It requires proportionality, which is not in general case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. To find a decomposition $A=B\otimes C$ you have to solve a system of $(KN)^2$ equations (the number of elements of $A$) with $K^2+N^2$ unknowns (the number of elements of $B$ and $C$). It is impossible, generally speaking.

**Example:** The matrix
$$
A=\left(
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
  \end{array}
\right)
$$
cannot be decomposed, since if $A=B\otimes C$ then 
$$
C=\alpha\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 \\
     \end{array}
\right) =
\beta\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    3 & 0 \\
    0 & 4 \\
     \end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: how about some special cases, say positive definite matrices?

Comment: It is the same. I will add the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If, say, the $(1,1)$ matrix element of $A \otimes B$ is $0$,  the $(1,1)$ matrix element of $A$ or of $B$ must be $0$.  And that implies at least
$\min(N^2,K^2)$ matrix elements of $A \otimes B$ are $0$.

Comment: Is there an iff (or if, or only if) condition when this is true?